# How to do a set union of two double floating point arrays but allowing a tolerance of error of 1 microsecond

Tags: c

I am trying to calculate the union of two arrays containing double floating point values (they are timestamps in milliseconds), but I need to allow a tolerance of +/- one microsecond.

For example: 
consider the two values from the two different lists (or arrays) below:

```
[ref   0 : 1114974059.841] [dut   0 : 1114974059.840]
```

there is a small delta between the above two numbers of .001 microseconds. So when I make my new union list, they shouldn't both appear as unique, but should be counted as ONE item, and should only have the item from the first list (in this example, ref one, ending in 059.841).

More examples of the above type:

```
[ref  21 : 1114974794.562] [dut  18 : 1114974794.560]
[ref  22 : 1114974827.840] [dut  19 : 1114974827.840]
[ref  23 : 1114974861.121] [dut  20 : 1114974861.120]
```

All the above should be considered as ONE, and hence the union list should ONLY have the ONE item of the first list: the union list would have all three from the `ref` array, and NONE from the `dut` array.

Now consider the example :

```
[ref   8 : 1114974328.641] [dut   8 : 1114974361.921]
```

Here, the delta between the two values in the list above is quite significant with respect to microseconds, and it comes under .01 micro-seconds, and hence should be considered as TWO unique items in the new union list.

Here is another example like the above one :

```
[ref  13 : 1114974495.041] [dut  12 : 1114974528.321]
[ref  26 : 1114974960.960] [dut  23 : 1114975027.520]
[ref  27 : 1114974994.240] [dut  23 : 1114975027.780]
```

They all should be considered unique in the new union list.

Can you help me?

I made a subroutine that allows me to detect the tolerance like this:

```
unsigned int AlmostEqualRelative(double A, double B, double maxRelDiff){
    double diff = fabs(A - B);      // Calculate the difference.
    // 
    if (diff < maxRelDiff) {
        //printf("\n page hit    [ref: %10.3f] [dut: %10.3f]",A,B);
        return 1;
    }
        //printf("\n page miss   [ref: %10.3f] [dut: %10.3f]",A,B);
    return 0;

}
```

I give maxRelDiff as .02.

Comment: Ok, `union` is a special data structure in C, and it is confusing. You are referring to a union of two sets in your question, right? I think you should clarify that.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what arrays you're dealing with. Do you have two arrays of doubles, with counters to indicate how full they are? Or are you using some kind of linked list?

You're definitely on the right track with your `AlmostEqualRelative(...)` function though. Although you could make that a `bool` instead of an unsigned int just for efficiency and to match convention. `unsigned int`s will work just as well though.

Comment: If you know how to write a regular 'union` operation using an equality operator, you can rewrite it by using the `AlmostEqual` operator in the same way.

Comment: @Dan : Yes, I two arrays of doubles. an array called ref and an array called dut which contains un-equal number of double floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two lists are of same size:

```
unsigned int // size of output array
union_list(const double *list1, // first list
           const double *list2, // second list
           double* ulist,       // output list
           unsigned int size)   // size of input list
{
    unsigned int i = 0u, j = 0u ;
    for(; i < size; ++i, ++j)
    {
        result = is_near(list1[i], list[2]);
        if (result == 1)
        {
            ulist[j] = list1[i] ;
        }
        else
        { 
            ulist[j] = list1[i] ;
            j += 1 ;
            ulist[j] = list2[i];
        }
    }
    return j ;
}
```

Now ulist is the output array. The maximum value it can contain is size*2 and minimum is size. Allocate max number of elements. The returned value is the size of the output array.

```
int is_near(double a, double b)
{
    int result = 1 ;
    if (fabs(a - b) >= relative_error)
        result = 2 ;
    return result ;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately my two lists are not of the same size :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

First, make a copy `foo` of the `ref` array. `foo` must be large enough to store both `ref` and `dut` arrays' elements as they may be mutually exclusive.

```
len=0;    
for(i=0;i<length_ref;i++)
        foo[len++]=ref[i];
```

Then, add to `foo` only those elements of `dut` which are not in `ref`.

```
for(i=0;i<length_dut;i++)
{
    flag=1;
    for(j=0;j<length_ref;j++)
        if(AlmostEqualRelative(dut[i],ref[j],MAXRELDIFF))
        {
            flag=0;
            break;
        }
    if(flag)
        foo[len++]=dut[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to rewrite your `AlmostEqualRelative` function as a function which conforms to the prototype `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)` (ie, return negative, zero or positive depending on the relative ordering of the arguments).  That makes it suitable for passing to the `qsort`(3) function.

That done, you could concatenate your two starting arrays, `qsort` the concatenation, and then work through the resulting array copying to a final result only a single exemplar of a sequence of elements which mutually `compar` to zero.

That would require a little bit of bookkeeping, and a bit of extra space, but it uses existing code (ie, `qsort`), and unless your arrays are so big that the extra space is a problem, it's probably the most straightforward route to a solution.

That is, this is the moral equivalent of getting the set-union of two files by doing `cat f1 f2 | sort | uniq`, but with some fuzziness on the `uniq` comparison.

Comment: Hmmm By redefining `==` for the `qsort()`, this leads to `A == B`, `B == C`, but maybe `A != C`.  I think this may fool `qsort()` too much and result in "sorted" arrays that are not fully sorted.  The "then work through the resulting array" becomes fuzzy on finding the "single exemplar".

Comment: Hmm, very true. Indeed, I think the question is fundamentally ill-posed, or at least a significantly more sophisticated problem than it may at first appear.  Consider a sequence of numbers (0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ..., 10.0).  Those are completely sorted, and_each one_ of those is ‘equal’ to its successor within a tolerance of, say, 0.15 (the definition of ‘equal’ that the OP wants, which is closer to the mathematical idea of [_equivalence_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)), but clearly 0.0 and 10.0 shouldn't be regarded as equivalent. This problem does not have an easy answer.

Comment: ...consider the notion of [well-definedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Well-definedness_under_an_equivalence_relation)